# AngularJS Google Charts

Tags: angularjs, charts, pygooglechart

[image: any ideas how to solve problem under charts?]

Hi there, any ideas how to solve data overlaping under charts?

```
  $scope.chart = [];
    $scope.chart.type = "ColumnChart";
    $scope.chart.cssStyle = "min-height:500px;height: 100%;width: 100%;margin:auto;background:#fff;text-align:center";


$scope.chart.options = {
    title: 'liczba subskrybujących'
  , height: 500
  , width: 1000
};

$scope.chart.formatters = {};
```

Here is how i attach data on the controller side.

```
var dt_data = results.data;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
data.addColumn('number', 'Subskrybujących');

angular.forEach(dt_data, function (datagive){
var date = datagive.day;
var total = datagive.total;
data.addRow([date, total]);
});

$scope.chart.data = data;
```

Comment: someone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old, but I decided to post anyway. Maybe op already got it sorted out.
Nevertheless, this may help people in the future. It works for me.

```
$scope.chart.options = {
title: 'liczba subskrybujących',
height: 500,
width: 1000,
hAxis: {
    title: 'You can have a title under the chart here',
    slantedText: true,
    slantedTextAngle: 90
    },
};
```

Google have documented this very well here [google charts.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/)

Yes that site is not exactly the angular variant, but most of the stuff there will work in angular google charts since it is based on google charts.

This may also help: [some good info on github for angular google charts](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart)